# Android NetworkInfo state with multiple networks active

Tags: java, android, android-networking

Fellow developers,

I'm developing an App which requires a use to be on a specific network at all times. I have no problem with listening for the "SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION" or "NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION". I would like to know what would be returned by

```
NetworkInfo info = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
info.getSubtypeName();
```

if mutiple networks are active? such as 3/4g and WIFI both active at the same time. I'm unable to test this because i'm testing on a tablet without 3g.

As some of you may realize, this doesn't check for connectivity to a specific WIFI. I have a different solution to that so please don't post answers saying ^^this doesn't work.

I notice calling

```
manager.getActiveNetworkInfo()
```

returns null if you don't have wifi or 3g turned on.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you do not need to test this as the `ConnectivityManager` makes sure you have only one connection active at any given time. That's why `getActiveNetworkInfo` returns only one `NetworkInfo` object.